# Set tableAttribute mapping dynamically in linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, mapping

I was wondering if it is possible to dynamically set the table mapping for the linq classes:

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[Comfort 0601$Contact]")]
    public partial class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
     ...
```

The reason I want to change this dynamically or programmatically is because the database I'm using is created by Navision. There the tables have a prefix of the company name to which these tables belong to. Therefor I would like to be able to change that prefix.

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name = "dbo.["+SPResources.Database.Company+"$Contact]")]
```

whit Company as:

```
    public const string Company = "Comfort 0601";
```

I've tried this, but it only work if i declared Company as a constant.

The table structure between companies are identical. just the name & content change.

I hope someone can give some advice about this. I'm also not sure if it even is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers of Brian and Gert are possible solutions for this problem. But changing the mapping at run-time is just not possible (as Brian mentioned).

As our project progressed we decided that if we would need another company name (which would mean that that build is for a different customer) we would just rebuild the project. That decision made the following solution possible:

We commented out the original mappings generated by Visual Studio:

```
//[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[Comfort 0601$Contact]")]
    public partial class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    ...
```

Because we have our own partial class for every Linq class, we added the modified mapping at the top of our own class:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name = "dbo.["+SPResources.Database.Company+"$Contact]")]
public partial class Contact
{
```

where our company will be:

```
public const string Company = "Comfort 0601";
```

If a rebuild is needed for a different company we simply change the Company variable.

**Note**: This only works properly if you don't change your *.dbml file in VS. If you do, VS will automatically undo your changes.

**Edit**: As time has passed and I started to look more into the Entity Framework I found a more specific and suitable solution for this problem: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421643/How-to-Use-MVC-Net-on-the-Dynamics-NAV-Database-St

Answer (score 2):

Think the correct solution for adding table-prefix is to use SQL Server 2005 (Or newer), and then create a db-user for each required prefix, and change default schema for each db-user from "dbo" to something unique.

Another solution is to extend the existing DataContext with the ability to "correct" the MappingSource at runtime:

```
[Table]  // Look no name
public class DbRecord
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

CustomDataContext.UpdateCustomTable(typeof(DbRecord), "DbTable");

using (CustomDataContext dc = new CustomDataContext(dbConnection))
{
    Table<DbRecord> dbTable = dc.GetTable<DbRecord>();
    var query = from item in dbTable;
}
```

This is the custom DataContext (I guess one could easily change it to add a prefix to an existing table-name) (Replace Dictionary with ConcurrentDictionary if in multi-threaded environment):

```
public class CustomDataContext : DataContext
{
    static CustomMappingSource _sharedMappingSource = new CustomMappingSource();

    public static void UpdateCustomTable(Type rowType, string tableName)
    {
        _sharedMappingSource.UpdateCustomTable(rowType, tableName);
    }

    public CustomDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : base(connection, _sharedMappingSource) { }
    public CustomDataContext(string fileOrServerOrConnection) : base(fileOrServerOrConnection, _sharedMappingSource) { }
}

internal class CustomMappingSource : MappingSource
{
    AttributeMappingSource mapping = new AttributeMappingSource();

    Dictionary<Type, string> _customTableNames = new Dictionary<Type, string>();

    public void UpdateCustomTable(Type rowType, string tableName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("TableName");

        _customTableNames[rowType] = tableName;
    }

    protected override MetaModel CreateModel(Type dataContextType)
    {
        MetaModel oldmodel = mapping.GetModel(dataContextType);
        CustomMetaModel newmodel = new CustomMetaModel(oldmodel, _customTableNames);
        return newmodel;
    }
}

internal class CustomMetaModel : MetaModel
{
    MetaModel _orgmodel;

    Dictionary<Type, MetaTable> _customtables = new Dictionary<Type, MetaTable>();
    Dictionary<Type, string> _tableNames = new Dictionary<Type, string>();

    public CustomMetaModel(MetaModel orgmodel, Dictionary<Type, string> tableNames)
    {
        _orgmodel = orgmodel;
        _tableNames = tableNames;
    }

    public override MetaType GetMetaType(Type type)
    {
        MetaTable metaTable;
        if (_customtables.TryGetValue(type, out metaTable))
            return metaTable.RowType;
        else
            return _orgmodel.GetMetaType(type);
    }
    public override MetaTable GetTable(Type rowType)
    {
        MetaTable customMetaTable;
        if (_customtables.TryGetValue(rowType, out customMetaTable))
            return customMetaTable;

        if (_tableNames.ContainsKey(rowType))
        {
            MetaTable orgtable = _orgmodel.GetTable(rowType);
            MetaType orgrowtype = orgtable.RowType;
            CustomMetaType newRowType = new CustomMetaType(orgrowtype, this);
            _customtables.Add(rowType, new CustomMetaTable(orgtable, this, newRowType, _tableNames[rowType]));
            newRowType.MetaTable = _customtables[rowType];
            return newRowType.MetaTable;
        }

        return _orgmodel.GetTable(rowType);
    }

    #region MetaModel Forwards
    public override Type ContextType { get { return _orgmodel.ContextType; } }
    public override string DatabaseName { get { return _orgmodel.DatabaseName; } }
    public override MappingSource MappingSource { get { return _orgmodel.MappingSource; } }
    public override Type ProviderType { get { return _orgmodel.ProviderType; } }
    public override MetaFunction GetFunction(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) { return _orgmodel.GetFunction(method); }
    public override IEnumerable<MetaFunction> GetFunctions() { return _orgmodel.GetFunctions(); }
    public override IEnumerable<MetaTable> GetTables() { return _orgmodel.GetTables(); }
    #endregion
}

internal class CustomMetaTable : MetaTable
{
    MetaTable _orgtable;
    MetaModel _metamodel;
    MetaType _rowtype;
    string _tableName;

    public CustomMetaTable(MetaTable orgtable, MetaModel metamodel, MetaType rowtype, string tableName)
    {
        _orgtable = orgtable;
        _metamodel = metamodel;
        _rowtype = rowtype;
        _tableName = tableName;
    }

    public override MetaModel Model { get { return _metamodel; } }
    public override MetaType RowType { get { return _rowtype; } }
    public override string TableName { get { return _tableName; } }

    #region MetaTable Forwards
    public override System.Reflection.MethodInfo DeleteMethod { get { return _orgtable.DeleteMethod; } }
    public override System.Reflection.MethodInfo InsertMethod { get { return _orgtable.InsertMethod; } }
    public override System.Reflection.MethodInfo UpdateMethod { get { return _orgtable.UpdateMethod; } }
    #endregion
}

internal class CustomMetaType : MetaType
{
    MetaType _orgtype;
    MetaModel _metamodel;

    public MetaTable MetaTable { get; set; }

    public CustomMetaType(MetaType orgtype, MetaModel metamodel)
    {
        _orgtype = orgtype;
        _metamodel = metamodel;
    }

    public override MetaTable Table { get { return MetaTable; } }
    public override MetaModel Model { get { return _metamodel; } }

    #region MetaType Forwards
    public override System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<MetaAssociation> Associations { get { return _orgtype.Associations; } }
    public override bool CanInstantiate { get { return _orgtype.CanInstantiate; } }
    public override System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<MetaDataMember> DataMembers { get { return _orgtype.DataMembers; } }
    public override MetaDataMember DBGeneratedIdentityMember { get { return _orgtype.DBGeneratedIdentityMember; } }
    public override System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<MetaType> DerivedTypes { get { return _orgtype.DerivedTypes; } }
    public override MetaDataMember Discriminator { get { return _orgtype.Discriminator; } }
    public override bool HasAnyLoadMethod { get { return _orgtype.HasAnyLoadMethod; } }
    public override bool HasAnyValidateMethod { get { return _orgtype.HasAnyValidateMethod; } }
    public override bool HasInheritance { get { return _orgtype.HasInheritance; } }
    public override bool HasInheritanceCode { get { return _orgtype.HasInheritanceCode; } }
    public override bool HasUpdateCheck { get { return _orgtype.HasUpdateCheck; } }
    public override System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<MetaDataMember> IdentityMembers { get { return _orgtype.IdentityMembers; } }
    public override MetaType InheritanceBase { get { return _orgtype.InheritanceBase; } }
    public override object InheritanceCode { get { return _orgtype.InheritanceCode; } }
    public override MetaType InheritanceDefault { get { return _orgtype.InheritanceDefault; } }
    public override MetaType InheritanceRoot { get { return _orgtype.InheritanceRoot; } }
    public override System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<MetaType> InheritanceTypes { get { return _orgtype.InheritanceTypes; } }
    public override bool IsEntity { get { return _orgtype.IsEntity; } }
    public override bool IsInheritanceDefault { get { return _orgtype.IsInheritanceDefault; } }
    public override string Name { get { return _orgtype.Name; } }
    public override System.Reflection.MethodInfo OnLoadedMethod { get { return _orgtype.OnLoadedMethod; } }
    public override System.Reflection.MethodInfo OnValidateMethod { get { return _orgtype.OnValidateMethod; } }
    public override System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<MetaDataMember> PersistentDataMembers { get { return _orgtype.PersistentDataMembers; } }
    public override Type Type { get { return _orgtype.Type; } }
    public override MetaDataMember VersionMember { get { return _orgtype.VersionMember; } }
    public override MetaDataMember GetDataMember(System.Reflection.MemberInfo member) { return _orgtype.GetDataMember(member); }
    public override MetaType GetInheritanceType(Type type) { return _orgtype.GetInheritanceType(type); }
    public override MetaType GetTypeForInheritanceCode(object code) { return _orgtype.GetTypeForInheritanceCode(code); }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Unfortunately, I have to work with dynamic table names and this solution was a drop-in replacement, even with the entities that a dbml generates.

Comment: Seems I'm not the first to think of this approach: http://jimmyyanblog.blogspot.dk/2008_12_01_archive.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SQLMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) to custom generate the code for each entities.  You cannot apply attributes dynamically at runtime, so this would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd work code-first you could use [fluent mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/hh272551.aspx) you can use the `ToTable()` method to configure the database table at runtime (see under *Changing the Database Table Name*). E.g. in a `OnModelCreating()` override of your DbContext derivative:

```
string company = "Comfort 0601";
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().ToTable(company + "Contact");
modelBuilder.Entity<....
modelBuilder.Entity<....
```

You could take the company name from a config file.